# how to rotate pages into landscape and page content should be in portrait iTextpdf

Tags: itext, xmlworker

I'm trying to create a PDF document with more than 2 pages in portrait and others in landscape,  I found that both page and text  rotates to landscape  I need  to prevent page content rotation. am using following code

```
 Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 36, 72);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new 
    FileOutputStream(outPutDirectory + indexID + ".pdf"));
    writer.setPageEvent(new Orientation(orientation));
    document.open();
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer,document, new ByteArrayInputStream(parserXHtml(page.getPageContent()).getBytes()))
    document.close();
```

my expected result should be like this

[image: expected result.pdf]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using a page event, you have to change the page size.

For instance:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new 
FileOutputStream(outPutDirectory + indexID + ".pdf"));
document.open();
// Add some content in portrait
document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
document.newPage();
// Add some content in landscape
document.close();
```

Be aware of the fact that the page size only changes on the next page. The order of `setPageSize()` and `newPage()` is important.

Comment: The OP does not say so but his code seems to imply that he wants to fill his document using the `XMLWorker`. Probably he isn't sure when new pages start and, therefore, attempts to use page events... (all pure guesswork, I admit)

Comment: OK, in that case, he might want to introduce some custom tag and extend the `TagWorkerFactory` to introduce the change in page size.