# How to use the 'page' property in iText / pdfHtml?

Tags: java, html, itext, itext7, pdfhtml

I'm using the @page rule to set specific options for pages.

I just found out that you can also define different properties for different pages by [naming them](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-page-3/#using-named-pages).
That would be quite useful, but it doesn't seem to work.
Although I can see that iText correctly interprets my named page and stores the name (I can tell, by monitoring `CssPageSelectorParser` and `CssPageTypeSelectorItem`), it seems to ignore the `page` property though, that is used to select which page to use.

Something like this should work, but it doesn't.

```
@page narrow { 
  size: 9cm 18cm;
}
@page rotated { 
  size: landscape; 
}
div { 
  page: narrow; 
}
table { 
  page: rotated; 
}
```

Is there any way of getting this to work or does this feature simply not work?

Cheers,
--Zuzu_Typ--

Comment: This feature is not supported for now. You can refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62778803/how-to-get-a-landscape-orientation-for-only-some-pages-while-converting-html-to/62804690#62804690) to see a potential way to implement similar functionality

Comment: Thanks! I'm already using your mentioned code to display pages in landscape orientation, the downsides are that you have to write a decent chunk of custom code to achieve it and that you loose the ability of using SVGs in your document (because `convertToElements()` can't hold SVG information). Having the 'page' property would make a bunch of things a lot simpler for end users. Having different headers / footers for specific pages (which isn't really possible currently), changing the page orientation on the fly, even possibly changing the entire page size / format. I'm looking forward to it.