# Change page orientation for some pages directly in HTML without using HtmlConverter.convertToElements()

Tags: itext, itext7, pdfhtml

I'm using pdfHtml and iText to convert an HTML document to PDF. There are some pages that need to be in portrait orientation and some that need to be in landscape orientation.
This needs to be configurable directly in HTML though.

The only working solution I found is https://stackoverflow.com/a/54232433/14014959, which uses `HtmlConverter.convertToElements()` in order to rotate the page when an element has a certain class (e.g. `.rotated`).
However this breaks a few other functionalities, such as the `@page` rule and SVG support.

There must be some other way of achieving the same with `HtmlConverter.convertToPdf()`, right?

Thank you for your help!

Cheers
--Zuzu_Typ--

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a landscape orientation for only some pages while converting html to pdf in itext 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62778803/how-to-get-a-landscape-orientation-for-only-some-pages-while-converting-html-to)

Comment: @AlexeySubach no, it does not. It is the same solution as the one I listed above.
I already specified that it would need to use `HtmlConverter.convertToPdf()`, because `HtmlConverter.convertToElements()` breaks other functions.